# Simplifying following expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Which cases Mathematica Simplify following expression?

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[b /c] Sqrt[c], c != 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which cases Mathematica Simplify following expression?

another option is to use Reduce to find what are the conditions. (I am assuming everything is real)

```
Reduce[Sqrt[b/c] Sqrt[c] == Sqrt[b], Reals]
```

gives

```
  c > 0 && b >= 0
```

For non real, remove the `Reals` above. Now the result is much more complicated as expected:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Simplify with the appropriate assumption, for example:

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[b/c] Sqrt[c], c > 0]
(*Sqrt[b]*)
```

Or also:

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[b/c] Sqrt[c], c < 0 && b > 0]
(*-Sqrt[b]*)
 FullSimplify[Sqrt[b/c] Sqrt[c], c < 0 && b < 0]
(*Sqrt[b]*)
FullSimplify[Sqrt[b/c] Sqrt[c], c > 0 && b > 0]
(*Sqrt[b]*)
```

In the case of radicals, you can also use PowerExpand:

```
PowerExpand[Sqrt[b/c] Sqrt[c]]
(*Sqrt[b]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Refine` also does the trick nicely. It's just a one-liner

```
Refine[Sqrt[b/c] Sqrt[c], c > 0]
```

> `Sqrt[b]`

And just to cover the cases examined by @E.Chan-Lopez

```
Refine[Sqrt[b/c] Sqrt[c], c < 0 && b < 0]
```

returns

> `I Sqrt[-b]`

and

```
Refine[Sqrt[b/c] Sqrt[c], c > 0 && b > 0]
```

> `Sqrt[b]`